# C-Extension: Ref count of generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api, refcounting

I'm trying to get the `Py_INCREF`'s and `Py_DECREF`'s for my c extension right.
Whilst doing so I've been stumbling about really high values for generators. What I've
been doing is the following:

```
// Forgive me for leaving out the NULL checks
PyObject *get_generator = PyUnicode_InternFromString("get_generator");
PyObject *callback;
PyObject *seq;
PyObject *item;

callback = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(parent->state, get_generator, NULL);
seq = PyObject_GetIter(tmp);

Py_DECREF(callback);

while ((item = PyIter_Next(seq))) {
    ...
    Code
    ...
    Py_DECREF(item);
}
Py_DECREF(seq);
printf("!!!%zd\n", seq);
```

Can somebody explain please.

Comment: `seq = PyObject_GetIter(tmp);` - do you mean `seq = PyObject_GetIter(callback);`?

Comment: And what is `printf("!!!%zd\n", seq);`? Do you think this is printing the reference count? This will print the pointer value. It probably wouldn't be valid to print the reference count there anyway since the object might well have been destructed

Comment: @DavidW I do mean ```seq = PyObject_GetIter(callback);``` and ```printf("!!!%zd\n", seq);``` is a stupid mistake of mine. I meant to write ```seq->ob_refcnt```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("!!!%zd\n", seq);` isn't printing the reference count, it's printing the raw pointer address (slightly incorrectly, since there is no guarantee that a pointer and a signed `size_t` are compatible for printing).

Also note that it's not safe to check the real reference count if you don't hold a pointer you own (or have borrowed safely), so checking after the `Py_DECREF` (when you gave up ownership) is undefined behavior.

To fix, change:

```
Py_DECREF(seq);
printf("!!!%zd\n", seq);
```

to:

```
printf("!!!%zd\n", Py_REFCNT(seq));
Py_DECREF(seq);
```

You should expect to see a count of 1 under normal circumstances, though if the object passed to `PyObject_GetIter` is itself an iterator (making `PyObject_GetIter` the identity function, doing nothing but incrementing the reference count and returning the otherwise unmodified argument), then the count could be higher if other references to the same iterator might exist elsewhere.

Assuming they weren't omitted simply for brevity, you do need to add checks for return values; virtually all of your API calls could return `NULL` if an exception is raised, and silently continuing processing rather than passing the error up immediately risks replacing a (useful) exception message/traceback with an (unhelpful) segfault.

Comment: Dooh... sry for my stupid mistake. The refcount is still high but within limits. I don't get why yet, but I might delete this question, as it holds no value for SO.

Comment: Even though I forgot the ```seq->ob_refcnt``` and my question was kinda stupid too begin with. Your answer was actually quite helpful.